# How to filter LinkedIn contacts

Tags: linkedin

I want to filter my LinkedIn contacts in order to delete some of them. How can I easily find and delete all my contacts who, say, are girls, aged between 26 and 32 and are from Tel-Aviv?

Comment: From what I can see, it doesn't look possible to filter by age, nor gender. But you can do location. This link (http://www.linkedin.com/contacts/search/?location=Tel-Aviv) should have location pre-filtered to Tel-Aviv if you want to use that for now.

Comment: thanks do you know how to see all my contacts easily?

Comment: [**Your LinkedIn Home**](http://www.linkedin.com/) > [**Network** Menu Option](http://www.linkedin.com/contacts/?filter=recent&trk=nav_responsive_tab_network) -- You could also click [***Connections***](http://www.linkedin.com/contacts/?filter=source&contacts_source=LinkedIn) under the same menu which will only show people you are connected to (i.e., sent/received a request that was sent/received by you/them. Rather than Network which is a collection of all people you are able to connect with by mutual connections).

Comment: it all leads to the same page. same hard to navigate view